# String.compareTo error with nullPointer exception

Tags: java, sorting, nullpointerexception, quicksort

Here, l have a quickSort that sorts an String array and where it starts and ends
sortA(String[] s,int start, int end)

```
String[] wordlist = new String[5000000];
QuickSort quickSort = new QuickSort();
int number = 0, startN = 0;

 public void read() throws IOException
{
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file you want to read from");
   String readFile = keyboard.nextLine();
   try
   {
     Scanner sc2 = null;
     sc2 = new Scanner(new File(readFile));
     startN = number;
     while (sc2.hasNextLine())
     {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
        boolean b;
        while (b = s2.hasNext())
        {
           String s = s2.next();
           s = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]","");
           wordlist[number] = s;
           number++;
           System.out.println(s + "|" +number);
        }
     }
     quickSort.sortA(wordlist, startN, number);
   }
   catch(FileNotFoundException e)
   {
      System.out.println("File not Found, please try again");
   }
}
```

l am reading from a normal file and trying to sort, but it gives me :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.String.compareTo(String.java:578)
 at QuickSort.partition(QuickSort.java:21)
 at QuickSort.sortA(QuickSort.java:7)
 at WordMatch.read(WordMatch.java:33)
 at WordMatch.main(WordMatch.java:73)
```

going to QuickSort.java:

```
  public class QuickSort
  {
    static void sortA(String[] s, int start, int end)
    {
      if (end > start)
      {
       int pivot = partition(s, start, end);
       sortA(s, start, pivot-1);
       sortA(s, pivot, end);
  }
}

 private static int partition(String[] s, int start, int end)
 {
  String pivot = s[end];
  int left = start;
  int right = end;
  String temp = "";
  do
  {
     while ((s[left].compareTo(pivot) <= 0) && (left < end))
        left++;
     while ((s[right].compareTo(pivot) > 0) && (right > start))
        right--;
     if (left < right)
     {
        temp = s[left];
        s[left] = s[end];
        s[right] = temp;

     }
  } while (left < right);
  temp = s[left];
  s[left] = s[end];
  s[end] = temp;
  return left;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seem wrong...

Comment: Maybe you could put a comment on the line that fails, to make it easier to help you, as the code doesn't contain line numbers

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.compareTo()` will throw a NPE if passed a `null`, which is what you must be doing.

Looking at your code, you are passing `s[end]` (via the variable `pivot`), so your array must contain null(s). Tracing back through the call stack, we see that the array being passed down is `wordList`, which is initialized with a size of `5000000`; unless you have *exactly* 5000000 words in your input, your code will throw an exception... 4999999 or less and you'll get a NPE, 5000001 or more and you'll get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

The remedy is captured by one of my favourite mantras: **Don't use arrays!**

Use a `List<String>`, which grows in size as you need, to capture the input. If your algorithm needs an array, convert the list to an array via List's `toArray()` method, which returns an array that is exactly the right size. This change will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks just about that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem with calling your quicksort `quickSort.sortA(wordlist, startN, number);`. Since before that line you have increased `number` in the loop, which means at the end `number` is having a increased value. you can try like this `quickSort.sortA(wordlist, startN, number-1);`

Thanks